# How i can maintain angular-fullstack client and admin different template

Tags: angularjs, angular-fullstack

I want to use different different types of template in client side and admin side using angular-fullstack.

Can you please let us know how i can achieve this. My routes look like Ex:

www.sitename.com - main site with theme1 (http://demo2.jlvextension.com/probusiness/)

www.sitename.com/administrator  - administrator dashboard with theme2 (http://www.theme-guys.com/materialism/angular/)

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35337836/ui-router-structure-for-restricted-admin-panel) is also a good solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me like you're trying to create two *very* different front ends. I recommend building two different angular applications that utilize the same api's and domain. You could put an entire admin angular application at www.[sitename]/admin.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

- you can resolve this problem with creating a directive with different
  templates,This [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WtF2A0yIgzS3V8fyuKA4) should demonstrate what needs to be done,
  but basically:(you should just change the value of isAdmin property
  to simulate ). `good luck`

Answer (score 0):

We also had a requirement like this and initially we had both in one SPA, where we distinguished each page by URL. The URL 'admin/login' loaded admin login page while '/login' loaded the login page for others. The $routeProvider config is given below.

```
   $routeProvider.when("/admin/login", {
        templateUrl: "app/admin/login.html",
        controller: "AdminCtrl"
    }).
   when("/login", {
    templateUrl: "app/user/login.html",
    controller: "LoginCtrl"
}).
```

Later when the application became big and difficult to maintain, we ported the admin part to a separate application like Gabriel suggested above.